# When is System.Convert.FromBase64String() implicitly called?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm getting an `Invalid length for a Base-64 char array` error, but it's not my code and I don't see any explict references to this function. I know that it could be a problem with the ViewState or a '+' decoding problem with Request.QueryString, but is there anything else where something is being implicitly converted to Base 64?

**Edit:** I'm just given a bunch of code and an exception message pointing to some pages, so I'm looking for absolutely anything related that could be suspicious - but I don't know what those look like. No debug privilages either so I have to just scan through and make guesses.

Comment: You'll need to provide a lot more context. For example, are you working with a SOAP web service with a char array parameter? If so, it could be that you are trying to pass a string to the service when it was expecting a base-64 byte array. The error is caused by the internal workings of the service when it attempts to convert the string as if it were a base-64 byte array.

Comment: @Cyborgx37 I'm not working with SOAP, but the problem is that I 'm not all that familiar with the context myself, so I'm just looking for related general problems/solutions others may have encountered.

Comment: The HTTP protocol provides no easy way to represent binary data. Base64 is a workaround - a way of at least compressing data into soemthing more compact then XML, etc. ASP.NET does a lot of this sort of compression behind the scenes (most notably the viewstate data). It would take some effort, but it's not difficult to corrupt this base64 data via one means or another. You are going to need to do some rather deep analysis to determine where that flaw is occuring. Tell your boss that you may as well be looking for a needle in a haystack in a cave without a light.

Comment: (Or diagnosing engine trouble by listening to the engine over a standard phone line... without being told what model car it is. Or performing exploratory surgery with a pocket knife and not knowing the species or symptoms. Or... well... you get the idea.)

Comment: (Also... I just gave you a general problem/solution I've encountered. There will be thousands of completely irrelevant problems/solutions without some additional context.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the debugger to find out exactly which line is causing the error. You can find this out by having the debugger break whenever an exception is thrown in your code. Do the following within Visual Studio (I am showing Visual Studio 2012):

1. Click the `Debug` menu.
2. Choose `Exceptions...`

You will now see the following:

[image]

As the picture shows, make sure the `Thrown` checkbox is checked for `Common Language Runtime Exceptions`.

Click `OK` and the next time you run your code, the debugger should halt at the line that is causing the `Invalid length for a Base-64 char array` error.